# full screen background colour css3

Tags: html, css

[image]I have a gradient as a background colour but it's just repeating. I want the gradient to stretch to full screen so it's not possible to zoom out and see any white space or repeated gradients.

Here is my css for the body

```
body {
text-align:center;
background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(238,238,238,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(89,89,89,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#595959',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `html { height: 100%; }` ?

Comment: @hsan that works when zooming out but now when I zoom in it repeats the gradien. I will upload an image so you can see what's happening with it now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to set the height and width on `body` and also try to use `background-attachment`:

```
html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body
{
    …
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I pasted your code in a test page and it seems to be doing exactly what you want. if you are having trouble with it, maybe you can try adding `background-size: 100%;`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've posted what it looks like when zoomed in now. The code doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

the following worked for me:

```
body
{
...
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Late answer worked for me `css`

```
:not(:root):fullscreen::backdrop{
    background: var(--bg-body);
}
```